# Any ideas about how to save the sound produced by runAndWait()?

Tags: text-to-speech, pyttsx

I'm using pyttsx3 to convert text to speech.

```
import pyttsx3

def tts(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

but the problem is that I can't save the sound to a file (which is so weird for a library like this).
I've tried some other alternatives like `espeak` which is the driver for pyttsx but the sound was bad even after tweaking some options.
If you have any suggestions of how can I save the sound or names of other offline libraries offering good speech quality (even with other programming languages) that would be so helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late answer but I hope it will be useful :)

```
# pip install comtypes
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

voiceList = []
for voice in voices:
    voiceList.append(voice.name)

print("Voice List: " ,voiceList)
def playItNow(textf, filename, useFile = True, rate = 2, voice = voiceList[0]):
    from comtypes.client import CreateObject
    engine = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
    engine.rate = rate # can be -10 to  10

    for v in engine.GetVoices():
        if v.GetDescription().find(voice) >= 0:
            engine.Voice = v
            break
    else:
        print("Voice not found")

    if useFile:
        datei = open(textf, 'r',encoding="utf8")
        text = datei.read()
        datei.close()
    else:
        text = textf

    stream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib

    stream.Open(filename, SpeechLib.SSFMCreateForWrite)
    engine.AudioOutputStream = stream
    engine.speak(text)
    stream.Close()


    import winsound 
    winsound.PlaySound(filename,  winsound.SND_FILENAME)    

playItNow("TextFile.txt", "test_2.wav", useFile= False, rate = -1)
```